# What is the purpose of setting follow to true in a LinkExtractor in a CrawlSpider?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I saw on the documentation they have this sample code for a CrawlSpider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('category\.php', ), deny=('subsection\.php', ))),

        # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
        item = scrapy.Item()
        item['id'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_id"]/text()').re(r'ID: (\d+)')
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_name"]/text()').extract()
        item['description'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_description"]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

From my understanding these steps will happen:

1. The Scrapy Spider (`MySpider`) above will get a response from the Scrapy Engine for the `'http://www.example.com'` link (which was in the `start_url` list). Then the `LinkExtractor` will extract all of the links from that response based on the two rules provided above.
2. Now let's say the second `LinkExtractor` (with the callback) got 3 links (`'http://www.example.com/item1.php','http://www.example.com/item2.php','http://www.example.com/item3.php'`) and the first `LinkExtractor` without the callback got 1 link (`www.example.com/category1.php`).

For the 3 links found above, the designated callback, `parse_item`, will be simply called. BUT, for that one link (`www.example.com/category1.php`) what will happen with that since there is no callback associated with it? Will the two `LinkExtractors` run on that one link again? Is that assumption correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
# and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
```

Since your `Rule` object has no `callback` argument, `follow` argument is set to `True`.
So in your example that 1 link will be crawled and links will be extracted from it just like it was done with the first page, this will continue until there are no more links extracted by the first rule or all of them were already visited.

Comment: Oh ok I see now. So essentially those two `LinkExtractors` will again extract the correct links from the response generated from that 1 link? Also is there a point of putting a callback when you set `follow=True`?

Comment: No, there's no point to provide a callback to follow links since you don't want to parse them manually anyways. Think of it this way, `follow=True` means it will callback to a _hidden_ callback that will just call all of the rules upon the response without doing anything else.

Comment: You stated `So in your example that 1 link will be crawled and links will be extracted from it`. When you say that one link will be crawled, you basically mean it will be crawled for the links based on the `LinkExtractors` correct?

Comment: @SigorEzz yup !

Comment: Okay, thank you! Technically though, I may need to parse out some items from the response of that 1 link. So for example after getting the response from that 1 link, I may parse out some items based in its callback, and then as you stated also have my other two LinkExtractors run against that response from the 1 link. I don't really see what you mean when you say `you don't want to parse them manually anyways`? Very sorry the abundance of questions and taking too much of your time.

Comment: In that case yes, you can use `callback` and `follow` together.

Comment: Ok got it :) Thank you for the explanation! :)